# C++ adding two QSliders together?

Tags: c++, qt, qspinbox, qslider

I have two `QSlider`-s/`QSpinBox`-es. Got those working but not sure about the best way of adding the two together to output the total.

Here is a picture of what I got:
[image]

Comment: Do not post pictures if you have a coding issue - post code!

Comment: You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors) and to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com). You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect signals form the sliders and spinboxes to slots in your main widget (or some other QObject derived class). Doing this allows your main widget to be informed whenever they are changed, do the addition, and output the result where you want. Check out some of the tutorials included with Qt for more info.